# Where do short-term traders look for the earliest stock related news?

Tags: trading, online-data-source, short-term, day-trading, news

While I'm no short term trader (or even a day trader), I imagine it is of high importance to these people that they hear about significant stock related news as early as possible. This would allow them to respond before competing traders do.

But where do these people get their news, especially those items specifically related to publicly listed companies (rather than a market or an economy as a whole)?

I imagine these are all sources on the internet, since other means would provide significant delay.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I work for a fund management company and we get our news through two different service providers
Bloomberg and Thomson One. They don't actually source the news though they just feed news from other providers
**Professional solutions (costs ranging from $300-1500+ USD/month/user)**

- http://thomsonreuters.com/
- http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/equities/
- http://www.iress.ca/

Bloomberg is available as a windows install or via Bloomberg Anywhere which offers bimometric access via browser. Bloomberg is superb and their customer support is excellent but they aren't cheap.

If you're looking for a free amateur solution for stock news I'd take a look at

- http://www.reuters.com/
- http://www.bloomberg.com/
- http://www.google.com/finance
- http://www.bing.com/finance

There are dozens of other tools people can use for day trading that usually provide news and real time prices at a cost but I don't have any direct experience with them

Comment: Thanks for your input. Could you elaborate on the "but they just feed news from other providers"? Does this mean that 1) these other providers delay their own news to get a premium from Bloomberg/Thomson or 2) these other providers publish their news at their own sites at the same time as they transfer it to Bloomberg/Thomson.

Comment: It'll be a mixture depending on the agreements Bloomberg has with it's news/research providers (there are over 1200). Timeliness of news is important but more often than not it will already be worked into the stock price, only unxepected news will trigger price moves. An amateur day trader doesn't have much hope of competing with the automated execution engines/institutional traders in terms of reacting to news that will cause a price change, in all likelyhood the price will have moved or be well on the way by the time you've read and digested the headline

Comment: I'm actually performing linguistic analysis as well so there is usually no need for me to read the article. It seems like noone really knows what these contracts look like, though.

Answer (score 8):

There's a whole industry devoted to this.

Professionals use Bloomberg terminals. High Frequency Traders have computers read news feeds for them. Amateurs use trading consoles (like Thinkorswim) to get headlines quickly on stocks.

Comment: Your answer is very concise. It makes sense that one uses news feeds. My question was _which_ news feeds they use ;) Bloomberg terminals sound interesting -- where can I read more about these? Are these paid services? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tom. Bloomberg will gladly sell you a terminal: http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/hardware/ The cost per month per terminal is in the range of USD1500-2000 as far as I have seen referenced.

Comment: @gef05, I don't quite get it -- why would I need to buy hardware? I am looking for news sources, used by short term traders.

Comment: @Tom. If you want access to the "news sources" you buy the hardware - it's a proprietary system, and the system includes both the info *and* the access to that info.

Comment: @Tom Most folks will get these services from their brokers. One of my brokers, TD Ameritrade, provides research from Credit Suisse, S&P, TheStreet.com, Jaywalk, Ford Equity Research and Goldman Sachs. They offer MarketEdge news as a premium subscription service.

Comment: @gef05 I'm talking about short-term traders here. So they wouldn't sell or buy because they believe the company is under- or overvalued, but they'd do it because they know that other traders are going to respond to the news. Thus, the news would have to be public -- correct? I expected people to link me to sources such as http://money.cnn.com/, http://www.bloomberg.com/news/stocks/ and http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks -- are these not used? Or are they significantly delayed?

Comment: @Tom "look for the earliest stock related news?"  To give the people answering your question some credit, you did ask how they get the earliest news.  Like duff mentioned different sources for each level of trader, maybe you want to specify further. Are you just looking for the average joe information? There are many systems and applications dedicated to short/day traders ranging from hundreds to couple thousand/month for access.  Short/day traders also trade on technical analysis of stocks.

Comment: @Tom, and where do you think these guys get the news? You think every press secretary calls every news outlet separately and tells them the news? No. A PR goes into the Bloomberg (Or Reuters, AP, or others), and all the news outlets get it from there and reprint. You want to get the **earliest** news? You don't wait for the reprints, you get the Bloomberg console for yourself.

Comment: @littleadv so why would only the bloomberg journalists get the headlines? If a CNN journalist posts something surely it will first be available at CNN.com, not on a Bloomberg terminal?

Comment: Bloomberg makes a business of being the first to get a lot of snazzy market-moving news to people FAST. Like, immediately. Consumer-oriented news sites are allowed to take their good old time: if your headline is 60 seconds late hitting the website because the journalist wanted to look up an appropriate .jpg file to go with it, nobody cares, but your trading opportunity is gone. Moreover CNN is not the first place you're going to hear a lot of market-moving news.

Comment: Also, for reference, the Bloomberg terminal can do things like this (scroll down for picture): http://www.bloomberg.com/professional/commodities/

Comment: @Tom - Bloomberg is not a journal and doesn't have journalists (for the terminal alerts, that is, they definitely have for their TV channels which is an entirely different business). Its a PR channel. They do have analysts and researchers who put alerts in additional to the press releases, I'm not sure if that can be considered as "journalists".